# Splitting an existing git repository

Tags: git, svn, migration

An SVN repository containing several projects, each in own folder, was migrated to Git. But the original structure was kept -  is any way to split the existing GIT repo, so each folder to be moved to own repo, but the history been kept?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subdirectory-filter` of `git filter-branch`.  For each directory you want to split out, you could for example

```
git clone --mirror origin-url
```

to create a local copy with all the history and refs, then in the clone

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter path/to/specific/project/in/repo --prune-empty -- --all
```

You'd want to look over the result to make sure it seems ok, and if so it can be used to populate a new origin repo for just that project.  First you'd probably want to remove the backup refs that `filter-branch` created (`refs/original/*`), and then depending on how you host your repos you could either use that as the origin, or init a new origin and `git push --mirror` to it.